# is it possible to explicity insert values in timestamp column of DB2

Tags: sql, database, insert, db2, timestamp

is it possible to explicity insert values in timestamp column of DB2? For example i have a date time value '2\11\2005 4:59:36 PM'. How to convert it to timestamp value in DB2?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO TimeStampTable(TIMESTAMPFIELD, ...) 
VALUES ((TIMESTAMP(CAST('04.02.2005' AS VARCHAR(10)),'13:14:53')),...)
```

Answer (score 6):

Another way to specify insert into timestamp field:

```
insert into mytable (timestamp_field, ...) values ('2018-07-25-14.56.11.000000', ...)
```

Comment: Amit is correct. you can simply specify the timestamp as a string. There are some restrictions on the formats which can be used. These are described here:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_datetimeconstants.html